# Integrate Sage Line 50 with windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-server, sage-erp, sage-line-50

I have to integrate C# Windows application with Sage Line 50. (To send all invoice details from application to Sage).

I searched on Google and most of the places it says to integrate Sage Line 50, we need to use
Sage development kit (SDK). But it's not free.

We already bought Sage Line 50. But now I want to know how we can integrate our accounting software with Sage Line 50?

I found this URL

```
http://crmsageconnector.codeplex.com/
```

they use Microsoft Dynamics CRM Connector for Sage Line 50 to synchronization of data, as well as data migration.

Comment: If you already bought the product, I would think you would be able to get the sdk as well (would pretty much suck if they will make you pay extra to get the sdk for a product you paid for). I doubt you are going to find a concrete intro as to how to do it here.

Comment: seems relevant, http://www.sage.co.uk/partnering-sage/developers/benefits/sdk.html. So does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661491/integrating-with-sage-financial-software

Comment: Highly unlikely that Line 50 comes with SDK. That's an entry level product. The Sage people like to charge you for everything they can. Since you know that you need the SDK, go ahead and get it. It costs money? You'll have to cough up then.

Comment: Could it be possible to integrate C# application with sage 50 using sage ODBC driver. But i need to read and write data to sage line 50 ?

Comment: IIRC The Sage ODBC driver is read-only. There is no way around the problem of writing to Sage without spending money and joining their developer program. You will find this is the case with most if not all ERP vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Sage 50 Accounts SDK is required if you want to integrate your accounting data to Sage...  And yes, it costs money: about £1500.

For this you get full access to the development support team (who are really helpful and know what they're talking about), the SDK DLLs, comprehensive SDK docs and the activation keys in order for you to start using the SDKs with Sage.

Note - the example codes are written in C# and VB.Net.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into exactly the same issue.
The Sage SDK is £1500 PER YEAR!!! and my understanding after speaking to Sage is that any applications developed with this years version would not necessarily work with future versions of Sage so you would need to spend ANOTHER!!! £1500 to get the latest dll's etc if your application needs updating for later versions. That’s too rich for me and more importantly my client.

I have been looking at alternatives and found SDATA at

http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/

This is quite tricky stuff but for anyone interested it is allowing me to query customer information and crucially it is allowing me to add and edit customers.  I’m going to try adding invoices next.

I’ve been using the link above and the example .net client here as reference

https://github.com/Sage/SDataCSharpClientLib

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hi Paul did you manage to get anywhere with SData as I contacted sage today and was told that sage does not support the SData modual yet I have sage 2016 and if you turn off SData you can not connect to the data stored in the data base

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise anyone replied until now.  Yes I did manage to do what I wanted with SDATA.  I managed to look up customers and create custom invoices which was what I wanted. There are a few sources of info but you can start here. It is definitely in latest Sage and has been for a while. http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/

Comment: I am still waiting for sage to implement spit data endpoint so that I can query tradingAccount and receipt endpoints any ideas on how this might be achevied with the current build of sdata as the accounts teams say they'll look at it but could take upto 18 month to implement

Answer (score 1):

Sage Data objects C# seems to be an alternative, paid one, but the website don't have download link working http://www.sagedataobjects.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply to become a sage developer over at http://www.sage.co.uk/partnering-sage/developers/index.html

Chose an option that suits you best and apply or you can hire a developer that has already paid to become a member to write the code for you (like me lol).

Answer (score 0):

You may find my product PostTrans which imports data from excel of use.   By using excel you can easily add you own code/macros/formula to manipulate data before posting into the Sage 50 accounts, with full validation and in cell search for codes.

idaea for data entry, or import of external data. see http://www.posttrans.co.uk/

Sorry for the advert, but may be of help ;_)

Comment: While Excel might be a good interim solution for novice users, having had to clean up "excel hell" applications where clients have butchered Excel to force it into doing something it was never intended to, when a simple little command line app could, this isn't really what we're after here.