# I am trying to synchronise a Sage Line 50 Accounting Software with Trackvia through API

Tags: php, api, sage-erp

I'm using Trackvia Cloud App as centralized Database all product info, Sales Order, Work orders.. are stored in Trackvia, i have also most of informations on Sage 50 Accounting, Is there anyway update Sage information based on TrackVia data and also update TrackVia information based on Sage data through API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trackvia just recently launched an API here https://developer.trackvia.com/

As long as Sage gives you a similar API it should be relatively easy to stitch them together.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can do this.  The easiest way requires you to purchase the Sage Account's SDK to gain access to their API - see my answer here [Integrate Sage Line 50 with windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582246/integrate-sage-line-50-with-windows-application/26612945#26612945) and on the web: https://shop.sage.co.uk/developersprogramme.aspx

The other way, involves accessing and playing around with the underlying tables using ODBC?  But I'm not 100% sure if that is the case. Certainly, this way is more difficult (but free) and is fraught with complications... as you need to know the names of the tables involved, their fields and the interaction with one another.  Other people may be able to help you out here.